# Inserting/adjusting png into plot [matplotlib]

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, imread

I'm doing illustrations for my paper in python using `matplotlib` library. In this illustration I have a lot of lines, polygons, circles etc. But then I also want to insert a `.png` image from outside.

Here's what I'm trying to do so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom='off', top='off', labelbottom='off')
ax.axis('off')

# drawing circle
ax.add_patch(
                plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.5, color = 'black')
            )
# drawing polygon
ax.add_patch(
        Polygon(
            [[0,0], [20, 15], [20, 40]],
            closed=True, fill=False, lw=1)
        )
# importing image
im = plt.imread("frame.png")
# defining image position/size
rect = 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4 # What should these values be?
newax = fig.add_axes(rect, anchor='NE', zorder=1)
newax.imshow(im)
newax.axis('off')

ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 60)
ax.set_ylim(0, 40)
plt.show()
```

So the question is, how do I determine the values for `rect = 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4`? E.g., I want the lower left corner of my `.png` to be at the point `[20, 15]` and I want its height to be `25`.

This is the resulting image:

[image: nonadjusted image]

But I want this dummy frame to be adjusted to my polygon points, like this (this one's adjusted in photoshop):

[image: adjusted in photoshop]

**P.S.** Here is the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIvKt.png) to the `frame.png` to experiment with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you plot your lines and the picture on the same axis?
for that, use the `extent` key in `plt.imshow()`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon


im='d:/frame.png'
img=plt.imread(im)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

frame_height=25
x_start=20
y_start=15
ax.imshow(img,extent=[x_start,x_start+frame_height,y_start,y_start+frame_height])

ax.add_patch(
        Polygon(
            [[0,0], [20, 15], [20, 40]],
            closed=True, fill=False, lw=1)
        )
ax.set_xlim(0, 60)
ax.set_ylim(0, 40)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Didn't think the answer would be that easy, though. Anyway, excuse me if the question was too stupid.